# Real performance boost with multiple partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partition, performance, disk-format

I have a 1TB Hard drive with multiple partitions where I had previously installed Snow Leopard. Now I'm making a clean install of Mavericks and I have a couple of questions:

1) What are the **real** performance advantages of having multiple partitions? Like one for the system, one for itunes, one for Home, ectr. Or maybe constantly accessing other partitions would in fact make the system slower? Reading around the internet literally everyone has a different opinion on this.

2) I'd like to make a good clean up before doing a reinstall: does it make any sense to format only the primary partition where the system will be installed leaving the other partitions for a re-formatation in the future (whem I'll have the necessary external hd to backup). Or it would be better a full hard disk erase and restart from there? And why?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have never, and I mean never, even back to the "classic" Mac O/S days (going back to system 6) partitioned a drive into smaller chunks.

Performance gains were supposedly about different parts of a rotational drive being faster than others (EG quicker seek to sectors near the physical hub). There may also have been some O/S speed gains in some O/S if you keep parts on different partitions, though I am not entirely sure as it has been years.

That said partitioning a drive does have some benefits, mostly when it comes to backup as it can be easier to back up all of one drive allowing you to easily exclude those things you don't want or need. On the other hand most backup programs allow easy inclusion or exclusion of types of file based on location and multiple other criteria.

Personally I have never bothered with partitioning as the few times I have had to use it I found it limiting to what I wanted or needed to do on the computer. In other words I would occasionally run out of room on partition "A" with plenty left on the other partition(s).

There is nothing inherently wrong with partitioning a drive but there is no real pressing need (or requirement) to do that with O/S X. And if there is no need/requirement I go with the first principle of good engineering: "KISS" or Keep It Simple, Stupid ;-)

As for question two, I suppose it depends on the availability of available backup space. If you have enough room to back up everything, do so and reformat the drive as one partition, then restore what you need to the fresh O/S install drive and go from there.

Comment: Thank you, regarding the question 2 do you have any comment?

Comment: I was talking more about indexing, fragmentation of the main partition and so on. I know that linking someone's random comment here is not a proper way to formulate a question but the first comment of [this post](http://www.larryjordan.biz/create-a-dual-boot-mac-os-x-system/) really hit me and made me puzzle if what's written there is the pure truth or complete misleading nonsense (and the reason I've asked this question).

Answer (score 1):

1) There are no performance gains from running multiple partitions. The drive is accessed sequentially and having 200 different partitions won't change that (the OS will not access each partition in parallel). The only way to boost storage performance is to run more than one using RAID0 (striped). Each hard drive can then be accessed separately and in unison, effectively doubling read speeds as data is segmented equally (in stripes) across both devices (note that write performance remains unaffected). One hard drive runs only as fast as one hard drive, regardless of how many partitions it has.

2) OS X installs intelligently. The OS install point is /System. Your user account (and the majority of all your files) reside in /Users. /Library holds both system and user (system wide) modifications and libraries. Drivers and other low level files are also installed here. If OS X is ever reinstalled, it removes the files in /System and simply replaces them with the new system. A reformat is not at all required and won't make a lick of difference to the stability of the operating system as the OS doesn't merely install overtop the old one. If you do wish to start fresh, however, boot into Internet Recovery (CMD + R), go to Disk Utility and simply repartition your hard drive and then reinstall OS X. Once done, use Migration Assistant to restore your user account and your respective data and installed applications.